# What does 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded do in http post method

Tags: angularjs, http, angular, xmlhttprequest, angular2-http

I still don't know how to make a correct http post method in angular 2, I did as they show on their official website.

I have this function createNewPlaylist in my api.service.ts

```
    createNewPlaylist(stDate: string, etDate: string, playlistTitle: string, shortTitle: string): Observable<any> {

 /**some code here **//
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(`https://cmsapi-dev.b2c.on.aol.com/v1.0/cms/playlists/${this.g_app}/${this.g_region}?trustedUserId=myuserid`,
             JSON.stringify({
              name: playlistTitle,
             shortName: shortTitle,
           }), options);
    }
```

And I have this function in my component

```
createNewPlaylist(stDate: string, etDate: string, playlistTitle: string, shortTitle: string):any {
    this.apiService.createNewPlaylist(stDate, etDate, playlistTitle, shortTitle)
    .map(res => console.log(res))
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
```

If i use the browser, enter the url directly (https://mydomain/v1.0/cms/playlists/aolon/us?name=asd&shortName=lalalal&method=POST&trustedUserId=myuserid), it will generate correct respond.

[image]

But my console get an error when I do it normally,

{"response":{"statusCode":478,"statusText":"Bad argument - name"}}

[image]
Any ideas?

**Update: I changed my code to this and it works, can someone explain to me?**

```
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


   return this.http.post(`https://cmsapi-dev.b2c.on.aol.com/v1.0/cms/playlists/${this.g_app}/${this.g_region}/?trustedUserId=myuserid`,
     `name=${playlistTitle}&shortTitle=${shortTitle}`,  options )
```

Comment: dont use json.stringify

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to set correctly the `Content-Type` header for your POST request:

- **implicitly** (from RC2)

  ```
  return this.http.post(`https://cmsapi-dev.b2c.on.aol.com/v1.0/cms/playlists/${this.g_app}/${this.g_region}?trustedUserId=myuserid`,
       {
         name: playlistTitle,
         shortName: shortTitle,
       });
  ```
- **explicitly**

  ```
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // <------
  return this.http.post(`https://cmsapi-dev.b2c.on.aol.com/v1.0/cms/playlists/${this.g_app}/${this.g_region}?trustedUserId=myuserid`,
       JSON.stringify({
         name: playlistTitle,
         shortName: shortTitle,
       }), { headers }); // <-------
  ```

Comment: I modify my question, did something like that, but it still give me error 478

Comment: Could you provide the request content from the Network tab of dev tools? Thanks!

Comment: Your request was correct but I guess that your server expects form-based payload (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and not JSON-based payload (`application/json`)... Your server should return a 415 HTTP status code in this case. The error would be more explicit ;-)